# TypeError: clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector is not a function in karma-jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a method which has an HTML element. I am trying to toggle the active class. It is working correctly but throwing an error while running the unit tests. Please find the error below.

```
buttonClick($event){
  const clickedElement = $event.target || $event.srcElement;

  if( clickedElement.nodeName === "BUTTON" ) {
    let isButtonActive = clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector(".active");
    // if a Button already has Class: .active
    if( isButtonActive ) {
      isButtonActive .classList.remove("active");
    }
    clickedElement.className += " active";
  }
}
```

Error is: TypeError: clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector is not a function

A unit test I have written is

```
it('buttonClick chnage the mouse event', () => {
    const event = {
            srcElement: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            },
            target: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            }
    };
    component.buttonClick(event);
    expect(1+1).toBe(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is making this call to `querySelector`:

`let isButtonActive = clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector(".active");`

Following a bit the trace, this comes from:

`const clickedElement = $event.target || $event.srcElement;`

---

Going now to your test:

You are calling the function with:
`component.buttonClick(event);`

The event data is:

```
const event = {
            srcElement: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            },
            target: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            }
    };
```

This will make `clickedElement` to be equal to:

```
target: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            }
```

Then, going back to:
`let isButtonActive = clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector(".active");`

Your `clickedElement.parentElement` will equal to:

```
{
  classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
  className: 'active'
}
```

This object does not have querySelector() function and hence why your test is failing.

One quick fix is simply add that function to event.target.parentElement like this:

```
const event = {
            srcElement: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            },
            target: {
                nodeName: 'BUTTON',
                parentElement: {
                    querySelector: (cssSelector) => {},
                    classList: ["btn", "btn-secondary", "btn-sm", "btnTemp", "active"],
                    className: 'active'
                }
            }
    };
```

This will surpress that error. Depending on whether you want to simulate the element to be active or not, you can decide what `querySelector: (cssSelector) => {},` will return.

---

All this being said, I think you should be testing this with real DOM and HTML instead of faking your own events. You are not really testing what you think you are testing. Some examples:

- [Fake HTML on JavaScript](https://christosmonogios.com/2016/09/08/How-To-Test-The-HTML-Elements-And-Their-DOM-Properties-When-Using-The-Jasmine-Framework/)
- [Proper HTML Page](https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/unit-testing-with-jasmine-the-very-basics-74k)

Comment: thanks for a lot for the detailed information and resources.